# Jquery mark all visible fields mandatory before submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have 20 fields in a form some of them are present in multiple divs which are set to `display:none` based on some conditions. I want to do a check when user clicks on submit all the visible fields must be required. 
Right now have written code on onClick events of few checkboxs but I feel that is not the efficient way to do.. instead if we can run a check by selecting all visible fields on click of submit button as required.

I'll really appreciate any guide for this case?

Comment: Can you show enough ("*[mcve]*") code for us to reproduce your problem? And, ideally, show us your own attempts detailing in what way they failed to work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you are not dynamically hiding and showing `div`s (because a template system does this before the HTML is served), then it is enough to mark all `input:visible` fields as `required` once, when the page loads.

```
$("input:visible").prop("required", true)
```

If you are dynamically hiding and showing `div`s (such as in response to button clicks, checkboxes, etc...), you will need to run that line each time fields are hidden or shown.

In this snippet, the first field is visible and the browser warns you if you try to submit when Field 1 is blank; however, the second field is hidden and therefore not marked as required. The browser doesn't complain that it is left blank.

Hope this helps!

```js
// if you dynamically hide/show any fields,
// make sure you re-run this line
$("input:visible").prop("required", true);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form>
  <div>
    <input placeholder="Field 1">
  </div>
  
  <div hidden>
    <input placeholder="Field 2">
  </div>
  
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks this approach helped .. I used conditional check to make it dynamic on for event based behaviour

Comment: No problem -- glad to hear success.

Answer (score 1):

You can match this code as per your requirement. I guess those visible and hidden fields are input types.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
                $("input:visible").each(function () {
                    $(this).prop("required", true);
                });
                $("#sbt").on("click", function () {
                    $('#myForm').find('input').each(function () {
                        if ($(this).prop('required') && $("#"+this.id).val()=='') {
                            alert('Please fill the required fields');
                            return false;
                        } 
                    });
                    //your submit code goes here
                });
            });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" id="myForm" name="myForm">
            <div id="fD">
                <input type="text" id="f1" name="f1">
            </div>
            <div id="sD">
                <input type="hidden" id="f2" name="f2">
            </div>
            <div id="tD">
                <input type="text" id="f3" name="f3">
            </div>
        </form>
       <button id="sbt">Submit</button>
```

Comment: Note: Checkbox if not checked is treated as hidden so on page load it is not set to required. If you want it to be done set required on click of form submit button.

Comment: Thanks aditya.. your appraoch is bit inefficient in my case compare to one suggested by ContinuousLoad.. this would have been useful if I need to do condition check on every visible element, but for me all are request if they are visible...

Answer (score 0):

I assume you hide or show your fields through some form of Javascript. HTML5 elements that you can access in JS can be set to required like so:

```
document.getElementById("someElement").required = true;
```

Obviously, the reverse is also possible.